# Foreach loop nested in For loop issue

Tags: php, parsing, loops, simple-html-dom

I have a script that parses through 23 pages of a page and grabs the names of a directory, However the connection resets and times out. Is it because of this nest foreachloop in the for loop?

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // this just makes sure encoding is      right
 include('simple_html_dom.php'); // the parser library

// you were trying to parse the wrong link.. your previous link did not have <div> tag with commentText class .. I chose a random link.. choose link for whichever professor you like or grab the links of professor from previous page store it in an array and loopr through them to get comments
 $i=1;
for($i; $i < 23;$i++){
$html = file_get_html("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/SelectTeacher.jsp?sid=834&pageNo=$i"); // the url for the teacher rating profile

 //your div tag has class "comment" not "commentText"
foreach($html->find("div[class=profName]") as $content){
 echo $content->plaintext;
 echo "<br >";  
  }
 } 


?>
```

Comment: use set_time_limit(0) to the loop

Comment: slamming a site like that with 23 requests in a row is likely to get your IP blackholed.

Comment: what do u suggest I do in order to retrive these records?

Comment: dude.. when I wrote loop through them(in your previous post) that didn't mean attack the web link so many times.. just grab the page and loop through div tags..

Comment: @Dinesh I'm new to this and my intent isnt malicious at all Dinesh, My apologies I didnt mean it. what is the ethical thing to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make a review website of my professor for my school, just a side project since Im out of school for the summer

Comment: we should see your code in `file_get_html()`

Comment: @Amir its from the parser library, it works I guess I'm just sending too many requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/),
It's pretty fast and would prevent your IP from getting black-listed...

Using it with PHP is fairly simple - [look here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_php).

Best of luck !